# Fully restart(discard and recreate) the whole flutter app programmatically

Tags: flutter

My app uses server responses when generating(building) different screens. I get the server responses at initState.

Re-building the screen(s) by setState will not trigger the initState. It will only update the state by setState input and re-build the widget.

Some actions in the app require fully restarting the app(for fetching all latest server responses and rebuilding the UI).

Rebuilding the whole app by

runApp(new MyApp()); (, or rebuilding all screens by setState of root screen)
is fine to refresh the UI widgets.
However, it cannot refresh all screens' state which holds the server responses.

e.g.

```
// MyState

String serverResponse;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  serverResponse = await http.get(url....
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Text(serverResponse);
}
```

App users can open many similar screens at the same time. 
When they change the state which will globally affect all screens. 
I cannot do

```
setState(() {
  serverResponse = await http.get(url....
});
```

for every opened screens when I want to reset the whole app.

I mainly have two questions.

1. If I want to keep the opened screens and their states.
   May I know is it possible to do something like flutter markneedsbuild?
   Instead of triggering the build only, I would like to trigger both initState and build when the screen is visited again. Does it violate the flutter design/flow?
2. If thing does not work like this, I think a simple way should be discarding all the previous screens and states. Everything starts over again.
   Is there any way to discard the old MyApp and re-create a new MyApp?
   So that all the states can be initialized again.

Many thanks for your reading and any of help!